# How to place planes for each face of frustrum in Unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

[image: Example Image]
How to place planes for each side of frustrum from a Blueprint ?

How to get the rotation and size for each side of camera frustrum from Bleuprints ?

Comment: Does the planes need to fit the shape as well?

Comment: @SamuelNg, Doesn't need to fit the shape,